# code how to get Internal/External storage of windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm confused how to get folder list in windows phone 8.1
is there anyone have ever experienced this or have any idea? 
I want to show all of the folder in storage in a listview
Thanks

```
var storageAssets = await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync();
ExternalStorageDevice item = storageAssets.FirstOrDefault();
ExternalStorageFolder folder = item.RootFolder;
var _folderList = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
foreach (var _folder in _folderList)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(_folder.Name);
}
```

I'm trying to show them using debug first before store in listview
but the code error says that ExternalStorage dosen't exist

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I have edit the post, i put the code there

Comment: I'm still new in C# windows phone, so i'm really confused

Comment: ExternalStorage are sdcards and stuff like that. Or are you trying to get the local storage folders ?

Comment: You are trying to get SD Card - have you turned it on in emulator or does it exist on Phone? Have you set up the Capabilities (RemovableStorage) in manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MSDN article and will do a better job of explaining than I can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx), but the summary is:

First you need the following in your manifest file:

```
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
```

and at least one file type declaration (these are the files that you will be able to access on the SD card:

```
    <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <FileTypeAssociation Name="foo">
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType ContentType="foo/bar">.bar</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
```

Then in your code to get the root of the SD card use:

```
StorageFolder sdCard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
if (sdCard == null)
{ return; /*no SD card*/}
```

and to enumerate the folders use:

```
 IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders = await sdCard.GetFoldersAsync();
```

Comment: <FileTypeAssociation Name="foo">
what does that mean?

Comment: You to choose a name for the file that you are associating with. For example, if you were associating with PDF files you might put "Portable Document Format File".